# Posting from controller to controllers with parameter gives an error

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

```
public function actionMyPluginActionControllerIndex(){
    $this->myPluginActionController($myVariable);
    return something;
}

public function actionMyPluginActionController($myVariable)
{
    return something;
}
```

This is giving me the error:

{"error": "Missing required parameters": myVariable"}

I did exactly this with a craft 2 plugin, but somehow this doesn's seems to work in craft 3 anymore, what am i missing?

any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You receive this error because `actionMyPluginActionController` expects a variable in it's parameters. You'll have to declare a default value

```
public function actionMyPluginActionController($myVariable = null)
```

or you need to declare something in your `actionMyPluginActionControllerIndex`

```
public function actionMyPluginActionControllerIndex(){
    $myVariable = 'foo';
    $this->myPluginActionController($myVariable);
    return something;
}
```

Unless you deactivated error messages/warnings on global level (via web config, dev mode off or something else), there is no way this would work in Craft 2 by default

Comment: That did the job! Note:


`Unless you deactivated error messages/warnings on global level (via web config, dev mode off or something else), there is no way this would work in Craft 2 by default` 

These cases were neither set, it was indeed the variable declaration.